# Regarding the outer measure of elementary sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

An elementary set of the space $[0, 1]^A$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a set ${E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$ for any finite ${B \subset A}$ and any Borel ${E_B \subset [0,1]^B}$, where $\pi_B: [0,1]^A \to [0,1]^B$ is the projection map. We also let $\mu_B$ be a probability measure on the cube $[0,1]^B$. One can then define the elementary measure ${\mu_0(E)}$ of any elementary set ${E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$ in ${[0,1]^A}$ by defining

$\displaystyle \mu_0( \pi_B^{-1}(E_B) ) := \mu_B( E_B )$

**Question**: For an elementary set $E \subset [0,1]^A$, if its’ outer measure $\mu^*(E)$ is shown to be such that

$\displaystyle \mu^*(E) = \inf_{V \supset E, \text{V open elementary}} \mu_0(V)$,

can we directly conclude from above the following:

$\displaystyle \mu^*(E) = \inf_{U \supset E_B, U \text{open}} \mu_0(\pi_B^{-1}(U))$?

My initial thought is no. Since if ${E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$ is elementary, then we know only $E_B \subset [0,1]^B$ is Borel, but the projection of a Borel set is not necessarily Borel, in particular, $E_B$ is not necessarily Borel in each coordinate of $[0,1]^B$, so the smallest open elementary covering of ${E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$ needs not take the form of $\pi_B^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is the smallest open cover of $E_B$. But we can directly obtain the conclusion for $E$ not only elementary, but also compact. Is this argument valid?

Comment: The notation $[0,1]^A$ is generally a very cumbersome notation for **all** functions $A \to [0,1]$. You might want to consider using a more standard notation if you want more responses.

Comment: @copper.hat: The notational convention is adopted by Tao himself in his note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/(see Exercise 14), I break the original question into pieces easier to work with.

Comment: Just sayin'... ${}$